# Read serial data without high CPU use

Tags: linux, serial-port

I want to read messages sent from an Arduino via the FTDI (serial) interface in a simple C or C++ program under Linux. The Arduino sends a two character 'header', a command byte followed by a few bytes of data depending on the command.

My first attempt was to simply poll the data using open() and read() but doing so causes about 12% CPU use. This didn't seem to be the appropriate way of doing things.

Second I read up on libevent on implemented an event loop that fires an event when data is present on the file descriptor. My cpu usage was next to nothing but I couldn't read the entire message before another event was called. The events didn't fire when an entire message was received but as soon as any/some data was available on the file descriptor. Looking at it more it was obvious that this wouldn't work quite the way I wanted it. This is my event code: http://pastebin.com/b9W0jHjb

Third I implemented a buffered event with libevent. It seemed to work somewhat better but still split some of the messages up. My event code is: http://pastebin.com/PQNriUCN

Fourth I dumped libevent and tried out Boost's ASIO class. The example I was following was http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html. It seemed to work alright but the "event loop" was a "while(1) {}" which caused CPU usage to go up again. The loop just checks for error status while serial reading happens in a callback on a different thread. I added a usleep(1) to the while loop and it brought my CPU usage to 2% which is ok, but still seems heavy for such a light program.

Most of the examples of libevent and even the underlying epoll use TCP sockets which doesn't seem to behave quite the same as serial port data.

So my main question is: what is a good lightweight way to read messages from a serial port without heavy polling? (in linux, using C or C++)

Comment: Were you using non-blocking `read()`? Does blocking `read()` not work for you?

Comment: The call `read` is a blocking call. Can you actually prove that the call to `read` was responsible for 12% CPU use, or were you just looking at a system monitor? If it really is that CPU intensive, try running it through `gprof` to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I usually use the Qt libraries for most things but it seemed a little heavy for this small task. Plus I love learning about "lower" level of API's. My first attempt used a blocking read() while my libevent tries used a non-blocking read(). I'll check into gprof and using a simple blocking read() tomorrow and report my findings back.

Comment: On Windows you can use the low level FTDI SDK library which bypasses the system serial port drivers altogether. Not sure if its available on linux, but if so then you could give that a go.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The OP has probably long since solved this, but for the sake of anyone who gets here by google:

```
#include <sys/poll.h>

struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd = serial_fd;
fds[0].events = POLLIN ;
int pollrc = poll( fds, 1, 1000);
if (pollrc < 0)
{
    perror("poll");
}
else if( pollrc > 0)
{
    if( fds[0].revents & POLLIN )
    {
        char buff[1024];
        ssize_t rc = read(serial_fd, buff, sizeof(buff) );
        if (rc > 0)
        {
            /* You've got rc characters. do something with buff */
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the serial port is opened in nonblocking mode as poll() can sometimes return when there are no characters waiting.

Comment: This post is not an answer to the original question/problem.  Nonblocking mode and polling before reading is not efficient use of the CPU.  Instead, a simple blocking read would utilize the built-in event-handling feature provided by the OS.  For responsiveness and efficiency, choose event-driven over polling.

Comment: @sawdust In spite of its name poll(2) uses essentially no CPU time while it's waiting for something to happen. It's more flexible than a blocking read() and can give a good tradeoff between responsiveness and number of characters read.

Comment: Your answer specifies nonblocking mode.  Why would poll() *"wait"* when nonblocking mode is in effect?  Nonblocking means always return immediately, with or without data available.

Comment: @sawdust I can assure you this technique works as in my answer above. I have developed many working applications that use this. Give it a try if you're in any doubt. But why does it work? See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html

"The operation of poll() and ppoll() is not affected by the O_NONBLOCK flag."

So why bother with O_NONBLOCK? See the note on spurious readiness notifications.